# VS Code Authentication to Github account prompt frequently without apparent cause

Tags: authentication, github, popup, prompt

I am encountering an issue with Visual Studio Code where it repeatedly prompts for authentication to my GitHub account without apparent cause. It results in multiple simultaneous pop-up windows for "GitHub sign-in." Even after successfully signing in, these prompts persist and reappear periodically. This situation has become increasingly disruptive and frustrating, despite I have installed Git Credential Manager. I believe that This is likely a local environment or permissions issue, and should be resolved by MS-VS-code.

Tried to consult with Github, and tried to install Credential manager. No use so far.